# How to avoid double freeing when raw pointer and unique pointer both refer to the same object?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

In the following code x (raw pinter) and p (unique pointer) are both pointing to variable a; so change of value "a”  is reflected both pointers dereferencing. I know that “p” takes ownership of &a. I am trying to understand the behavior of pointers when they go out of scope, which pointer gets released first?  How can I avoid double freeing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    int a = 5;

    int *x = &a;
    std::unique_ptr<int> p(&a);

    *p = 6;
    std::cout<< *x << *p <<'\n';
    // prints 66
    *x =7;
    std::cout <<*x <<*p <<"\n";
    // 77

    std::cout  << "Done!"<<'\n';
}
```

P.S. I get this runtime error ”pointer being freed was not allocated"

Comment: You cannot use `std::unique_ptr` with objects allocated on stack (well, not unless you provide a custom deallocator, which does nothing to the object). Why do you even do that?

Comment: There is no double free in your code. Normal pointers don't release anything when they're destroyed.

Comment: @melpomene he's constructing a `unique_ptr` from the address of an automatic variable. That *will* cause problems when both the automatic and the `unique_ptr` are destroyed.

Comment: @JesperJuhl True, but that has nothing to do with the `int *x` pointer. (And normally "double free" refers to the `free()` function or equivalent, not automatic storage.)

Comment: @melpomene I agree that it has nothing to do with the raw pointer.

Comment: "*I know that “p” takes ownership of &a.*" Well, it tries to, but it really can't. `a` already owns itself; you can't take that away.

Comment: "I know that “p” takes ownership of &a" - No. You are wrong. The `unique_ptr` cannot take ownership of a automatic variable. You need to go back and re-read your C++ books.

Answer (score 11):

`std::unique_ptr<int> p(&a);` is simply a bug, since `a` is an automatic variable that will be destroyed when it goes out of scope. And you just created a situation where a `unique_ptr` will *also* try to destroy the same object. Just don't do that.

You seem to assume that if you form a `unique_ptr` to an existing object, then that new `unique_ptr` will have exclusive ownership of the object. This is wrong.

Also; raw pointers do not delete what they point to when they are destroyed. This has *nothing* to do with your raw pointer.